# Huygens’s pendulum use in daily life

Tags: curves

I want to know how is Huygens’s pendulum used in the daily life.Are there any real world applications or something?

Comment: By "Huygens's pendulum", do you mean one where the bob is constrained to move along a cycloid rather than a vertical circle?

Comment: yes i mean that only.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are any practical applications nowadays.

Huygens invented the cycloidal pendulum in an attempt to improve the accuracy of pendulum clocks (though I'm not sure if it was ever put to use for this purpose), but pendulum clocks are an outdated technology anyway, practically only produced for decorative/educational/sentimental purposes.

For practical timekeeping, much better accuracy than pendulums can be achieved cheaply and robustly using [quartz clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_clock), which depend on piezoelectrically driven vibrations of a small carefully calibrated quartz crystal.

Comment: Do you know any practical applications for theBrachistochrone curve problem?